# What book had different staircases appearing at night in a child's room?

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a book I read when I was younger, probably in the 90s (although my nan used to buy me books at every boot fair she went to so it could be much older) that I would class as fantasy.

In the story I remember two children, I think a boy and a girl who were siblings, and a staircase used to appear in their room at night that led out the window. The staircase was always a different colour/material and led to different places where they would have adventures.

I also remember something about fairy rings. I think the book was hardback with a red fabric cover but I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: The description for ["The Hidden Stairs and the Magic Carpet"](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/1061388.The_Hidden_Stairs_and_the_Magic_Carpet) isn't an exact match, but has some elements in common - could it be the one?